# Css inherited value doesn't show in Chrome inspector

Tags: css

I know that if any value is inherited it would show in the inspector.
[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
    div#outer {width: 500px;}
    div#inner {text-indent: 10%; color: blue;}
    /*p {width: 200px;}*/
</style>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="outer">
        <div id="inner">
            This first line of the DIV is indented by 50 pixels.
            <p>
                This paragraph is 200px wide, and the first line of the paragraph
                is indented 50px.  This is because computed values for 'text-indent'
                are inherited, instead of the declared values.
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

I think the width of div#inner is inherited from div#outer, but it shows up in **computed** column not in **style** as something **inherited**. Why? Do I misunderstand something?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Width isn't inherited. An in-flow block box with auto width expands to fit as much horizontal space as its containing block allows, but that's not the same thing as inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

Inner html dom element will always cover it's parent's width , considering that no change is there in display properties of child.